# Ethereum client implementation

Tags: evm, clients

I think to better my understanding of the EVM and underlying file system, I want to read through one or more ethereum client implementations and potentially build a client myself. So far I've been slowly digging through the pyehtereum client since it's the easiest to read. But it is still quite challenging. I was wondering if there are any resources that walks through a client implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the javascript version[EthereumJs-VM](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm)

Comment: The user is asking for a walk-through, not for another EVM implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now (March 2020), I'm not aware of any clear documentation, and have heard from others that there is not. I seem to recall that one of the goals of [Trinity](https://github.com/ethereum/trinity) was to serve as an easier-to-parse implementation. In any event [Py-EVM](https://github.com/ethereum/py-evm), their EVM implementation, should be more up-to-date than pyethereum. If you're specifically interested in the EVM, I know that [this](https://github.com/corepaper/evm) project was aimed at writing a full spec, though I don't know how far they got, or if it's still active or not.

There is also an [Awesome EVM](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Virtual-Machine-(EVM)-Awesome-List) page, but it's a bit old.